# How to replicate this javascript onclick using requests?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have this button in a website:

```
<a data-page-number="6" data-offset="150" href="website.com/etc.html" class="pageNum taLnk" onclick="      require('common/Radio')('restaurant-filters').emit('paginate', this.getAttribute('data-offset'));; ta.trackEventOnPage('STANDARD_PAGINATION', 'page', '6', 0); return false;
  ">
6
</a>
```

The website shows a list, and to move to page list 1,2,3,etc.. you have to click on the above button, the `data-offset` is what controls which page list the website is showing.

I want to replicate clicking on this button using requests, is that possible?

Comment: When you say replicate pressing the button, are you parsing the website and just trying to parse multiple pages?

Comment: Also if you look at the urls for the pages themselves, what do they look like going from page to page

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: Please add your current coding attempt.

Comment: @MendelG  the url  is the same for every page, it doesn't change when you change the page

Comment: @RolvApneseth yes i'm trying to parse all the pages but i can't move to the next pages because the "next" button does not change the link, so i have to somehow send that "data-offset" attribute to the page when opening it so that i can move to the next pages.

Comment: you haven't given us any url though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was able to send the "data-offset" attribute manually by using this code

```
requests.get('url', params={"data-offset":"2220"}).text
```

Comment: Good that you managed to figure it out but next time please try to provide more information in your question. Still, up voted cause you managed to find a solution that works properly for you